# How to get targeted file/folder information when implementing a COM object using IContextMenu interface

Tags: winapi, com, windows-shell, shell-extensions

I want to customize the menu you get when you right-click on a folder on the windows desktop and windows explorer. As The text displayed by my menu should be dynamic (depending of the folder path), I implement the `IContextMenu` interface in a C++ Dll and specify the `CLSID` and DLL path in my registery.

It works, when the user right click on a folder, the shell call my `IContextMenu::QueryContextMenu` fonction and I can insert my `MENUITEMINFOA` struct in the `HMENU`. Then the user can see it in the context menu.

**My question** is how to get the folder path the user has right-click on before inserting my `MENUITEMINFOA` struct in the `HMENU` So i can adapt what I put in the `MENUITEMINFOA.dwTypeData` ?

I tried to implement the `IShellExtInit` interface as it seems the shell can give information using this interface but when I log the call to my dll I see that the shell never call `IShellExtInit::Initialize`.

I guess the shell give the information via an interface I didn't implement but I found no clue on the documentation. However this seems possible to do as, for example, TortoiseSVN do it : the context menu show "SVN Checkout..." on some folder and "SVN Update" / "SVN Commit..." on some others.

I wish you a nice day :)

Comment: `IShellExtInit` should be called through your `QueryInterface` implementation right after `IContextMenu` and the `IDataObject` member will contain the list of items selected that you can get using the `SHCreateShellItemArrayFromDataObject` method . Your code has probably some issue, it should work (all Windows version) Please provide a minimal reproducible sample https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Implement IShellExtInit when you are writing a handler based on the IContextMenu.For more details I suggest you could refer to the Doc:[Customizing a Shortcut Menu Using Dynamic Verbs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shortcut-menu-using-dynamic-verbs) [Implementing IShellExtInit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/handlers)

Comment: Thanks guys for the confirmation that it should be done through `IShellExtInit`. But I guess @SimonMourier is right, there are probably some issue with my code, the way I compile it or my windows installation as I observe some strange behavious (The shell doesn't ask for a `IShellExtInit`, it asks for object with IID that doesn't exist (at least for COMView and `StringFromIID`), and the shell doesn't call DllMain when I declare a `std::stringstream`). I will try on other computers. If I observe the same behavious on different computers I will share a minimal reproductible sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem Solved**

The shell do ask for a `IShellExtInit` just after asking for a `IContextMenu`. I was just confuse by the fact that `StringFromIID` and COMView don't know the IID of these interfaces (but thanks to @SimonMourier's tool [www.magnumdb.com](https://www.magnumdb.com/search?q=%2astackoverflow%2a), I could confirm the IID the shell asked was these interfaces).

The (main) issue was I didn't cast my object to the interface asked (I though it wasn't needed as long as my object expose the right methods). When I `static_cast` my object on the `IShellExtInit` interface when asked for, the shell do call `IShellExtInit::Initialize`.